# SQL Query insert values and show without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Okay So i am busy with a `php` code where when i click the insert button i want the values to display without reloading the page. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'universitynew');


$sql="SELECT * FROM tblstudent";
$student_records=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);


?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script type='text/javascript' src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="Student.php"class="btn btn-primary active" role="button">Student table</a>
    <a href="Degree.php"class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Degree table</a>
    <a href="Subject.php"class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Subject table</a>
    <a href="assessment.php"class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Assessment table</a>
    <a href="student_assessments.php"class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Student Assessment table</a>
    <a href="Degree_student.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Student Degree table</a>
    <a href="Student_Subject.php"class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Student Subject table</a>
    <hr></hr>
    <table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <input type="button" name="insertrecords" id="insertrecords" value="Insert Records" />
    <span id="success" style="display: none">Successfully Inserted</span>
    <div id="response"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#insertrecords").click(function () {
                $("#success").show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "insert_student.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'action':'submit'},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#success").hide();
                        if(data.status=="true"){
                            $("#response").html(data.universitynew);
                        }else{
                            $("#response").html("Error in db query");
                        } 
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
    <h1><a href="insert_student.php".php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Delete Students</a></h1>
    <h1><a href="insert_student.php".php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Update Students</a></h1>

    <tr>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <th>Student number</th>
    <th>Student name </th>
    <th>Student surname</th>
    <th>Student course</th>
    </tr> 
    <?php
    while ($student=mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_records)){
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>".$student['student_id']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$student['student_number']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$student['student_name']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$student['student_surname']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$student['student_course']."</td>";
        echo"</tr>";


    }


    ?>
```

I managed to do some `jquery` and ajax for the button which displays successfully inserted and it does insert to my database my problem arises by displaying the table without reloading the page. Could anyone help me do this?

Comment: Did you write some jQuery code?

Comment: @Ilyaskarim i did for the button but i dont know how to write jQuery for the displaying of the updated results, thats where my problem arises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the show function in jQuery:

```
$('#success').show();
```

For a detailed guide check this: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Edit:
Just saw that you are using the function, your problem is that you're using hide whenever the request succeeds, you need to use it if it fails.

```
$("#insertrecords").click(function () {
  var request = $.ajax({
      url: "insert_student.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'action':'submit'},
      dataType: 'json'
  });
  request.done(function(data){
  $("#success").show();
    $("#response").html(data.universitynew);
  });
  request.fail(function(error){
    $("#response").html("Error in db query");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When ajax gets complete you need to show  `#success` element.The element is hidden through CSS display property with value `none`. You can simply change display property to `block` so it will be visible on ajax success:

```
$('#success').css("display","block");
```

You can also show element by jquery `show()` function

```
$('#success').show();
```

You can find more here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Edit:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
  dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
  data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
  $("#success").show(); // this will show the message 
  ...
})
.fail(function() {
  ...
});
```